# mongodb looking in wrong directory for data

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I have installed a mongodb on my ubuntu and to my surprise mongodb is looking in the wrong data directory.

In in mongod.conf it says:
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb

However, when I start the mongod serve from my terminal it says:
exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating

Any suggestions why my mongodb is not correctly loading the config file?

Comment: Try providing DB path using --dbpath attribute while starting mongoDB

Comment: Are you using the default conf file `/etc/mongodb.conf` or have you named it something else.

Comment: With --dpath I can make it point to the right folder but I want the config file to work correctly. Yes the config file is in the default folder /etc/mongod.conf.

Comment: how is it possible that it works when I do sudo mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf but when launching it with sudo service mongod start I get an error in the log Assertion: 28595:13: Permission denied src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 267